# Closing websocket connection error

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

Hello I'm using websockets on my node.js server in order to stablish WebRTC connections. But when I end the connection the node server console gives me the following error:

```
        conn.otherName = null;
                       ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'otherName' of undefined
```

Other name is the name of the other Peer and I'ts setted up in the connection like this:
    case "offer": 
            //for ex. UserA wants to call UserB 
            console.log("Sending offer to: ", data.name);

```
        //if UserB exists then send him offer details 
        var conn = users[data.name]; 

        if(conn != null) { 
           //setting that UserA connected with UserB 
           connection.otherName = data.name; 

           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "offer", 
              offer: data.offer, 
              name: connection.name 
           }); 
        } 

        break;

     case "answer": 
        console.log("Sending answer to: ", data.name); 
        //for ex. UserB answers UserA 
        var conn = users[data.name]; 

        if(conn != null) { 
           connection.otherName = data.name; 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "answer", 
              answer: data.answer 
           });
        }
```

Afterwards I'm closing the connection like this:

```
connection.on("close", function() { 

  if(connection.name) { 
     delete users[connection.name]; 

     if(connection.otherName) { 
        console.log("Disconnecting from ", connection.otherName); 
        var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
        conn.otherName = null;  

        if(conn != null) { 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "leave" 
          }); 
        }  
     } 
  } 
});
```

How can I change it to be able to close the connection without crashing my node server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stopping it from breaking is quite simple with some defensive code, change this

```
var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
conn.otherName = null;
```

to this

```
if (connection.otherName) {
    var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
    if (conn) 
         conn.otherName = null;  

    if(conn != null) { 
// The connection is closed, trying to send at this point isn't a good idea
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "leave" 
          }); 
        }  
    }
```

It doesn't address why users[connection.otherName] is returning undefined (that's an exercise for you), but it will stop it crashing

Comment: It crashes anyway, the problem is that when I click twice the button which sends the "close" message. As it has already been closed it returns undefined so it crashes showing the same error log.

Comment: I have added another defensive if statement to the answer - this is a strategy you should take throughout your code to prevent this kind of error happening. I also added a comment to ask why, when you are in the on close handler, you are trying to send a message? This seems like a bad thing to try and do.

Comment: It worked thanks! It's put that way to send to the other endpoint the leave so the call ends.